# Truncate and rename subdirectories within a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have several folders named:

```
001TRIAL1
002TRIAL2
003TRIAL3
...etc.
```

I'm trying to rename all folders using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) and truncate them in order to get:

```
TRIAL1
TRIAL2
TRIAL3
...etc.
```

I have tried this code:

```
for /D %%X in (C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\*) do (
    move %%X %%X:~3,10%
)
Pause
```

But I'm unable to get the result I want.

This script does not work and I don't know how I can do that. The rename allows to rename folders but I'm not able to truncate the folders that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expand a metavariable like that, you need to set the value to a proper variable, then perform the expansion. Additionally, as the variable would be set within a code block, you'd need to enable delayed expansion. Finally, you'd use `Ren`ame not `Move`, which would require that the directory already existed, *and you'd need to delete the original directory post rename*.

Try this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%A In ("C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\*") Do (
    Set "_d=%%~nxA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not Exist "%%~dpA!_d:~3!" Ren "%%A" "!_d:~3!"
    EndLocal
)
```